# Beginners: Error in defining JPA one to one Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following tables:

```
Login -> (id, username, password)
Members -> (member_id, name, address)
```

id is related to member_id with one to one mapping.

I wrote two models as

Login Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Login", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username") })
public class Login {

private int id;
private String username;
private String password;
private Members members;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "member_id")
public Members getMembers() {a
    return members;
}

}
```

Memeber Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Members")
public class Members {
private int member_id;
private String name;
private String address;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "property", value = "Login") })
@Column(name = "member_id")
public int getMember_id() {
    return member_id;
}

private Login login;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Login getLogin() {
    return login;
}

}
```

I have dropped few getters and setters for simplicity. Anyways can you tell me where am I going wrong? I get errors like mapping not found, persistent class not known etc etc while altering the values of annotations.

**ERROR**

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [database/Hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on org.sparsham.login.model.Login.members references an unknown entity: org.sparsham.members.model.Members
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Comment: Why do you have a property of the class Members IN you Members class? You should define a property of the Login class in your Members class.

Comment: @WesleyVrancken thats one stupidity I did. I changed that. Please have a look. Now my error is @  OneToOne or @ ManyToOne on org.sparsham.login.model.Login.members references an unknown entity: org.sparsham.members.model.Members

Comment: Have you configured your entity classes in your hibernate.cfg.xml or equivalent?

Comment: @JensSchauder am using Spring. What should I do to configure in this case? Earlier without mapping I was able to insert into Login table. Now after mapping its showing error.

Comment: You should also refrain from mixing JPA and Hibernate annotations, from my experience this can lead to errors. You also need a mappedBy="members" in your @OneToOne annotation in the Members class.

Comment: @WesleyVrancken okay. just let me know how to use the annotations in this case. this is my first attempt at writing a One to One mapping

Comment: Just stick to the annotations included in the javax.persistance package, so that means removing that org.hibernate CascadeType. Make sure you adjusted everything we mentioned here then update your post and include the precise error message if you are still getting one.

Comment: @WesleyVrancken as u said i've added the error message changed the cascade part. Please have a look at the error and let me know how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Your Members class is still not being found, this probably means you forgot a mapping in your configuration file. Double check that and post it here.

Comment: @WesleyVrancken u were right. i added that mapping. but now the sql being generated is insert into Login (members_id, password, username) values (?, ?, ?). Can't figure out how this is happening. Actual column name is id and not member_id in Login

Answer (score 1):

Hope this fixes the last of your problems. Try these changes.

Login model :

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Members getMembers() {a
    return members;
}
```

Members model :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = { @Parameter(name =          "property", value = "login") })
@Column(name = "member_id")
public int getMember_id() {
    return member_id;
}

private Login login;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="members")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Login getLogin() {
    return login;
}
```

Pay attention the the @Parameter part in the @GenericGenerator annotation, "login" is probably case-sensitive.

Comment: the last problem still exists. insert into Login (members_id, password, username) values (?, ?, ?). The mappedBy = "members" value gets prefixed with the primary key in login.